# Debian has randomly occurring kernel panics at boot

Tags: debian, boot, kernel-panic

I have a QNAP server on which I installed Debian 10 and then 11, using RAID 1, as recapped in the screenshot below:

[image: recap of RAID and partitions]

It works fine most of the time, but with both versions I've been randomly experiencing kernel panics at boot time like in this boot screen:

[image]

As this happens randomly, I only have to reboot a few times before I get it running back properly (it boots correctly with no errors). Still it's quite annoying, so I'd like to fix it.

Comment: In order to identify the kernel crashes more in depth, you need to enable kdump. This is how you can do it in debian - https://superuser.com/a/946474 . After you have a dump please use crash to read it and post it here or in another thread

Comment: thanks @Alex for the hint, I'm going to do as you recommended asap

Comment: thanks @Alex for the hint, I'm going to do as you recommended asap, but...

https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/kdump-tools/kdump-tools.5.en.html

"By default, kernel dumps are stored locally on the system" or "kdump-tools can be configured to store the kernel dumps on a remote server accessible through the network."

I can understand this might work for a running system which crashes after having properly booted (so, having had access to local filesystem or the network), but I'm quite doubtful it could work for a system which is yet-to-boot!

Are you sure kdump would work there?

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/managing_monitoring_and_updating_the_kernel/using-early-kdump-to-capture-boot-time-crashes_managing-monitoring-and-updating-the-kernel

Kernel crashes during the booting phase occur when the kdump service is not yet started, and cannot facilitate capturing and saving the contents of the crashed kernel’s memory. Therefore, the vital information for troubleshooting is lost.

To address this problem, RHEL 8 introduced the early kdump feature as a part of the kdump service.

Comment: It appears the panic is the result of previous errors, you may want to check out why `Initramfs unpacking failed: uncompression error` happens.  Which `initramfs` are you attempting to load and why can it not be uncompressed on random occasions?